# Access Query total

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get a total for 24 data entries done on a given day.  I have a date, name, and value.  Yes a value is generated every hour.  Can i do that in a query and if so any hints on how to get what i am looking for.

Here is a sample of the data.
_

```
TIMESTAMP   IDName  SumOf_VALUE
6/13/18 1:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    193479.2656
6/13/18 2:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    191460.9531
6/13/18 3:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    169738.5938
6/13/18 4:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    171580.0938
6/13/18 5:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    158367.4531
6/13/18 6:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    151303.2813
6/13/18 7:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    148457.6563
6/13/18 8:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    151200.3594
6/13/18 9:01 AM EFF_Flow_MGD    154745.0156
6/13/18 10:01 AM    EFF_Flow_MGD    179623.25
6/13/18 11:01 AM    EFF_Flow_MGD    193257.0938
6/13/18 12:01 PM    EFF_Flow_MGD    201511.2813
6/13/18 1:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    210372.8906
6/13/18 2:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    203826.0625
6/13/18 3:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    205648.4531
6/13/18 4:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    200690.2656
6/13/18 5:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    201725.4531
6/13/18 6:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    199851.2656
6/13/18 7:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    190038.3281
6/13/18 8:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    188712.25
6/13/18 9:01 PM EFF_Flow_MGD    197430.9531
6/13/18 10:01 PM    EFF_Flow_MGD    176996.25
6/13/18 11:01 PM    EFF_Flow_MGD    190499.0313
```

**EDIT - added SQL tried (from comments)**

```
SELECT Sum(dbo_new_stuff1.[_VALUE]) AS SumOf_VALUE, dbo_new_stuff1.IDName, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP] 
FROM dbo_new_stuff1 GROUP BY dbo_new_stuff1.IDName, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP] 
HAVING (((dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP])>#6/12/2018 16:0:0#)) 
ORDER BY dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can able to pull the query that I want.  I did try the sum tab to give the sum of the number grouped by date.  But it does not change the query at all.

Comment: here is the SQL of what I have  SELECT Sum(dbo_new_stuff1.[_VALUE]) AS SumOf_VALUE, dbo_new_stuff1.IDName, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]
FROM dbo_new_stuff1
GROUP BY dbo_new_stuff1.IDName, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]
HAVING (((dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP])>#6/12/2018 16:0:0#))
ORDER BY dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP];

Comment: Since the GroupBy has both IDName and _TIMESTAMP and since a timestamp has minutes and seconds and we see nothing but ';01', I suspect that there is only one data row per hour... so I question why _TIMESTAMP is needed in the GroupBy??

Answer (score 1):

We need to reduce the _TIMESTAMP to its date component... so try this.
This first attempt will only work in SQLServer, not  MSAcccess.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(date, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]) as justDate
    ,dbo_new_stuff1.idname
    ,Sum(dbo_new_stuff1.[_VALUE]) AS sumof_value
FROM     dbo_new_stuff1
GROUP BY dbo_new_stuff1.idname, CONVERT(date, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]) 
HAVING   (CONVERT(date, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]) >#6/12/2018#)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]), dbo_new_stuff1.idname ;
```

Thanks to Thomas G for correcting me to give an MSAccess solution --

```
SELECT
   Int( dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]) as justDate
    ,dbo_new_stuff1.idname
    ,Sum(dbo_new_stuff1.[_VALUE]) AS sumof_value
FROM     dbo_new_stuff1
GROUP BY dbo_new_stuff1.idname, Int( dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]) 
HAVING   (Int( dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]) >#6/12/2018#)
ORDER BY Int( dbo_new_stuff1.[_TIMESTAMP]), dbo_new_stuff1.idname ;
```

Which gives this result--

```
justDate    idname          sumof_value
6/13/2018   EFF_Flow_MGD    4230515.5001
```

Comment: This wont work in MS-access SQL. `CONVERT` is not a valid function, its `Cdate`. It might work if its a pass-through query and the tables are on SQL server, but the OP didn't specified that, even though the tables are named `dbo_` something which indicates SQL Server's default schema. They might be linked tables from SQL server DB, but if it is the case the SQL syntax from MS access prevail and this query will fail.

Comment: @Thomas G  Thanks for correcting me to supply an MSAccess solution.